# Execute a function when mouse is over any button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page where I have replaced my cursor with a `div`.
The cursor is simply a part of the page that I can animate using `CSS`.
The main thing I want to achieve is to make this cursor change size when I hover over any button.
I cannot get it to work...

Cursor positioning is handled by a JQuery script but the vanilla one doesn't seem like it wants to work with me...
I can can't fix the error...

```js
// Jquery code that moves the cursor (div element)
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
 $('#cursor').css({
  left: e.pageX - 7,
  top: e.pageY - 7
 });
});

// Function to be executed when mouse is over a button
document.querySelectorAll('button').addEventListener("mouseover", cursorHovering);

function cursorHovering() {
 document.getElementById('object').style = "transform: scale(2);";
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

*, body { cursor: none !important; }
#cursor {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20000;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    pointer-events: none;
}
body:hover #cursor {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <button class="button1">Hover over me (1)</button>
  <button class="button2">Hover over me (2)</button>
  <button class="button3">Hover over me (3)</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```js
// Jquery code that moves the cursor (div element)
var c = document.getElementById('cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => { 
  c.style.left = e.pageX - 7 + 'px';
  c.style.top = e.pageY - 7 + 'px';
});

// Function to be executed when mouse is over a button
document
  .querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(b => {
     b.addEventListener("mouseover", () => c.style.transform='scale(2)');
     b.addEventListener("mouseout", () => c.style.transform='scale(1)');
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

*, body { cursor: none !important; }
#cursor {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20000;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    pointer-events: none;
}
body:hover #cursor {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  
<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <button class="button1">Hover over me (1)</button>
  <button class="button2">Hover over me (2)</button>
  <button class="button3">Hover over me (3)</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Something like this but I really want to use regular JavaScript because it's easier for me to manipulate it...

Comment: @FalsePride there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla JS solution.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);

// Cache the elements
const cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// For each button add the two event listeners
[...buttons].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOver, false);
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut, false)
});

function handleMouseMove(e) {

  // You need to ensure that you add "px" to the
  // end of the value. jQuery does this automatically.
  cursor.style.left = `${e.pageX - 7}px`;
  cursor.style.top = `${e.pageY - 7}px`;
}

function handleMouseOver() {
  cursor.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
}

function handleMouseOut() {
  cursor.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

*,
body {
  cursor: none !important;
}

#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20000;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  pointer-events: none;
}

body:hover #cursor {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <button class="button1">Hover over me (1)</button>
  <button class="button2">Hover over me (2)</button>
  <button class="button3">Hover over me (3)</button>
</body>
```